# Mascaras - angular 2

Tags: angular

Estou precisando implementar em um campo mascaras do CNPJ ou CPF, isto é, se for acima de 14 caracteres muda a mascara para CNPJ.

Mesma ideia para telefone, isto é, celular e fixo.

CNPJ, CPF, Telefone, Celular, único eu já vi no npm.

Qual vocês utilizam ?

Comment: amigo: uso eeses: https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks e https://github.com/the-darc/angular-br-filters.

Comment: Mas estes não são para angular 1.x.x ?

Answer (score 0):

Fiz assim:

```
  public cpfcnpjmask = function (rawValue) {
         var numbers = rawValue.match(/\d/g);
         var numberLength = 0;
         if (numbers) {
           numberLength = numbers.join('').length;
         }
         if (numberLength <= 11) {
           return [/[0-9]/, /[0-9]/, /[0-9]/, '.', /[0-9]/, /[0-9]/, /[0-9]/, '.', /[0-9]/, /[0-9]/, /[0-9]/, '-', /[0-9]/, /[0-9]/];
         } else {
           return [/[0-9]/, /[0-9]/, '.', /[0-9]/, /[0-9]/, /[0-9]/, '.', /[0-9]/, /[0-9]/, /[0-9]/, '/', /[0-9]/, /[0-9]/, /[0-9]/,  /[0-9]/, '-', /[0-9]/, /[0-9]/];
         }
       }
```

Componente no html

```
<input matInput placeholder="Login" name="login" 
               [(ngModel)]="usuarioBuscar.login" [textMask]="{mask: cpfcnpjmask}" 
               matTooltip="Login do usuário" maxlength="20">
```

E funcionou. Segui a mesma lógica para telefone e celular. Usando a lib angular2-text-mask.